# How can MySQL table be sorted by numeric field with filled null-gaps?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Assume I have table like this:

```
id | name | priority
---------------------
1  | ...  | null
2  | ...  | 1
3  | ...  | 4
4  | ...  | 2
```

What I need is *one* sql query which will select all raws sorted by priority and with filled gaps with `null`-values.

Result:

```
id | name | priority
---------------------
2  | ...  | 1
4  | ...  | 2
1  | ...  | null
3  | ...  | 4
```

I know how to use `order by`, but `null-`values always get in the end or at the start of the query result... No idea how to fill the gaps with `null`s while maintaining `priority`-order.

Comment: Assuming that there is more than one row with a `null` priority, which one should go between 2 and 4?

Comment: @GregSchmidt, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Which version of MySql?

Comment: This would definitely be easier to do in the client programming language, which can loop over arrays easily.

Comment: @trincot, MySQL 8.0

Comment: @Barmar, it won't be easier - I need `limit` / `offset` also and table may contain many rows, more than 100k

Comment: The basic starting point is to create a table with sequential numbers, left join that with the non-null `priority` values to get all the missing priorities. Then you have to somehow replace the null priorities with those, but I'm not sure how to do that in SQL. A join will create a cross product, not substituting them one at a time. Maybe there's some way to do this with window functions, I'm still not really familiar with them.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you! Also thought about cross joins today but still don't know where to start from. Will think more on this :) Yes, I know what SO for. Thank you!

Comment: SQL is just a poor language for doing sequential merging of unrelated data. It's not a relational operation. Languages with arrays and loops are much more suited to this.